# Increment $index in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How should the $index in `ng-repeat` be incremented by a specific value?
For instance in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11811/ the value needs to be displayed two at a time. So the next iteration should start with third value instead of second value.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="text in arr">
   <span>{{arr[$index]}}</span> 
   <span>{{arr[$index+1]}}</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a custom function in your controller that returns numbers from 0 to the length of your array, skipping every other value in between.

**[Modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2j16ckw/)**

Here, I created a function called `$scope.range()`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.arr=['hi1','hi2','hi3','hi4','hi5','hi6','hi7'];

    $scope.range = function(max, step) {
        step = step || 1;
        var input = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= max; i += step) {
            input.push(i);
        }
        return input;
    };
}
```

Use this new function in your `ng-repeat` by specifying the maximum number of elements to use and the number of elements to skip.  So, to show every other element in `arr`, you would use `num in range(arr.length, 2)`.

The function will create and return an array to the `ng-repeat` that looks like this:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Your `ng-repeat` will be repeated four times (once for each item in this array) which corresponds to four rows. Then the two `<span>` elements will use the current value and the one after it to provide you with two columns.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="num in range(arr.length, 2)">
    <span>{{arr[num]}}</span> 
    <span>{{arr[num+1]}}</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also modified your `<span>` elements to use `arr[num]` and `arr[num+1]` instead of using `$index`.  This provides the results you're looking for.

You can, of course, modify this to use three columns by just changing the 2 to a 3 in the `ng-repeat` like this:  `<div ng-repeat="num in range(arr.length, 3)">`

See the **[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2j16ckw/)**.

Comment: Great.. this was exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: how to apply these to labels and input type